# Filter out the price or cost in the Java

Tags: java, regex

I have got `((?:[0-9]{1,3}[\.,]?)*[\.,]?[0-9]+)` to filter out the prices in a string on java so I put them like this:

```
public static final String new_price = "((?:[0-9]{1,3}[\\.,]?)*[\\.,]?[0-9]+)";

final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(new_price, 0);
    final Matcher m = p.matcher(label);
    if (m.matches()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "found! good start");
        if (m.groupCount() == 1) {
            Log.d(TAG, "start match price" + " : " + m.group(0));
        }
        if (m.groupCount() == 2) {
            Log.d(TAG, "start match price" + " : " + m.group(1));
        }
    }
```

I got the sample working on http://www.regexr.com/ but it never found the matches on the run time.  Any idea??

Comment: Should we guess how does your input look like, and what exactly are you trying to match? or will you be generous enough to share these small details with us?

Comment: string sample:    ```$500.00 - $522.30 ``` I would expect to get 500.00 and 522.30

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `matches()` you should run `m.find()` which searches for the next match (this should be done in a `while` loop!):

```
String new_price = "((?:[0-9]{1,3}[\\.,]?)*[\\.,]?[0-9]+)";
String label = "$500.00 - $522.30";
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(new_price, 0);
final Matcher m = p.matcher(label);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("found! good start");
    if (m.groupCount() == 1) {
        System.out.println("start match price" + " : " + m.group(0));
    }
    if (m.groupCount() == 2) {
        System.out.println("start match price" + " : " + m.group(1));
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
found! good start
start match price : 500.00
found! good start
start match price : 522.30
```

Comment: so I should never start with .matches() ?

Comment: @HeskeyoKam I have the feeling that you're confusing `Matcher.matches()` with `String.matches()`, here's a [good regex tutorials](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)

Comment: so I have finally built the correct way to find my matches. Here is the code just for the reference.